# display series data not mapping to the xAxis in ECharts

Tags: javascript, visualization, echarts

I have an ECharts line chart that can display my data when the yAxis series array data has the same length with the xAxis data (in the code and image below I think it means they are 'perfectly matched' and binded, e.g `['0', 59.4], ['4', 65.7]` etc.).

But I also want to make some data that not showing in the xAxis can be binded too. For example data like `['3', 60.1]` (which means when the x is 3, the y is 60.1) should also be binded too. How can I make it in ECharts ?

```
var option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        axisLabel: {
          show: true,
          interval: 0,
          textStyle: {
            color: '#333333',
            fontSize: '11',
          }
        },
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: ['0', '4', '8', '12', '16', '20', '24'],
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        data: [59.4, 65.7, 69.8, 73.3, 76.5, 77.7, 78.1]
      }, {
        name: 'B',
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        data: [60.7, 67.1, 71.4, 74.9, 78.1, 78.8, 79.2]
    }]
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intermediate values should have a value (not a category) x-axis. There are two possibilities:

1. Change the existing axis so it's a value axis; this means you have to adjust the original data set to include x values:

```js
var option = {
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'value',
        axisLabel: {
            show: true,
            interval: 4,
            textStyle: {
                color: '#333333',
                fontSize: '11',
            }
        },
        min:0,
        max: 24,
        minInterval: 4,
        maxInterval: 4,
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24],
    },{
        type: 'value',
        min: 0,
        max: 24,
        show: false
    }],
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        data: [[0,59.4], [4,65.7], [8,69.8], [12,73.3], [16,76.5], [20,77.7], [24, 78.1]]
    }, {
        name: 'B',
        type: 'line',
        xAxisIndex: 1,
        smooth: true,
        data: [[3, 60.7], [6,67.1], [9, 71.4], [12, 74.9], [15,78.1], [18, 78.8], [21, 79.2]]
    }]
};
    
const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart-container'));
myChart.setOption(option);
window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
```

```html
<div id="chart-container" style="height:350px"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.1/echarts.min.js"></script>
```

2. Add a secondary value axis, not visible, just for the new data. Care should be taken in this case to make sure the new axis is at the same position as the default category axis.

```js
var option = {
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'category',
        axisLabel: {
            show: true,
            interval: 0,
            textStyle: {
                color: '#333333',
                fontSize: '11',
            }
        },
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24],
    },{
        type: 'value',
        min: 0,
        max: 24,
        show: false
    }],
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        data: [59.4, 65.7, 69.8, 73.3, 76.5, 77.7, 78.1]
    }, {
        name: 'B',
        type: 'line',
        xAxisIndex: 1,
        smooth: true,
        data: [[3, 60.7], [6,67.1], [9, 71.4], [12, 74.9], [15,78.1], [18, 78.8], [21, 79.2]]
    }]
};

const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart-container'));
myChart.setOption(option);
window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
```

```html
<div id="chart-container" style="height:350px"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.1/echarts.min.js"></script>
```